# Why does it only sums the last two numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a program that sums every number given as parameter. To do so, I wrote the following code:

```
var x = 0;
var i = 2;

while (isNaN(+process.argv[i + 1]) == false){
    x = +process.argv[i] + +process.argv[i + 1];
    i++;
}

console.log(x);
```

The problem is that the code I wrote sums only the 2 last parameter.

I launch my code using `node sumArgs.js 1 2 3`
and it returns `5`.

What is the problem with my code and why isn't it working as planned ?

Comment: what is `process` contains? paste full code.

Comment: Whatever the content of process is, since i starts from 2, how is it supposed to sum all the numbers? i should start from zero, not from 2, shouldn't it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @Mike process.argv contains an array of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening every time you loop through, it is taking the current parameter, and the next, and setting x to equal the sum of those.

x needs to be added to, not set. You can do this either:

```
x += process.argv[i]
```

or

```
x = x + process.argv[i]
```

I'm also not sure why you are adding 2 arguments each loop, as this will cause the sum to be incorrect at the end (unless you increment i twice each loop).

I should note that map reducing it, as in another comment, wouldn't work as the first 2 arguments would not be parameters passed to the program, they would be "node" and "program.js".

```
var x = 0;
var i = 2;

while (isNaN(+process.argv[i]) == false){
    x = x + process.argv[i];
    i++;
}

console.log(x);
```

However, what you could do is use slice:

```
var sum = process.argv.slice(2).reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});
```

Comment: I have added an example using the map reduce that would allow you to make your code much more succinct, and still ignore the first 2 argv elements.